# Performe AR Foundation similar to ARKit's SetWorldOrigin

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, arkit, angular-foundation

Since unity ar foundation didn't implement ARKit's method SetWorldOrigin() (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arsession/2942278-setworldorigin)
I want to make world center to become first found tracked image.

When I found image with ARFoundation's TrackedImageManager, I want the found tracked image's transform position to become unity world's center.

Anyone faced the same problem? How could this be made?

Answer (score 0):

It is apparently not possible to change the actual world origin with ARFoundation, c.f. https://forum.unity.com/threads/ar-foundation-re-positioning-world-origin.540135/.
You will have to position a parent GameObject at the transform of the tracked image and position everything using local position/rotation.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [MakeContentAppearAt(Transform, Quaternion)](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.xr.arfoundation@2.1/api/UnityEngine.XR.ARFoundation.ARSessionOrigin.html) if you want to show your content on the tracked image without actually moving the virtual content in the scene. Just pass tracked image position and local rotation to the function.